# Нестыковка ковычек ' и " при вызове функции функции

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

В HTML файле вызываю функцию:

```
onclick="func('stackoverflow.ru', 'lol "lol"')"
```

Но из-за двойных ковычек выходит ошибка. 
Если было бы `func('stackoverflow.ru', 'lol lol')`, то есть без ковычек, тогда всё работает, но с ковычками ничего не выходит, (коллизия).

Строка у меня является переменной из Java (Я могу с ней делать то что угодно, но скобки должны оставаться), могу делать `String.replace(старый символ, новый символ)`, но скобки должны оставаться.

Не подскажете как можно заменить строку так, чтобы HTML её нормально в функцию отправлял? Или что сделать, чтобы ковычки нормально работали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `onclick='func("stackoverflow.ru", "lol lol")'`

Comment: Нет, я мои строки выглядят вот так: stackoverflow.ru , lol "lol" , то есть в строке должна быть ковычка

Comment: Мне нужно в функцию передать именно "stackoverflow.ru" и "lol "lol" " типо этого

Comment: `onclick='func("stackoverflow.ru", "lol \"lol\"")'`

Comment: Посмотри пожалуйста скриншот, я отредактировал первый пост, у меня не работает /" asd /" , какие еще есть альтернативы не подскажешь?

Comment: использовать другие кавычки `onclick='edit("asd \"asd\"")'`

Comment: Не передавать все данные через параметры функции, лучше хранить их где-нибудь в html отдельно. Потому что потом появятся проблемы с \n, потом с каким-нибудь другим управляющим символом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать экранирование нужных символов, а также "правильные кавычки" и их последовательность:

```
onclick='func("stackoverflow.ru", "lol \"lol\"")'
```

С учетом скриншота:

```
onclick='edit("asd \"asd\"")'
```